# Calculate distances between various places in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I have the following problem: I have two lists of addresses X and Y, both as an excel table or csv file, and would like to use Google Maps to automatically calculate the distance between each possible location x of X and y of Y. It would be great if there was a way to export the data in the form of a matrix, again as either an excel table or a csv file.

Does anybody know whether Google Maps has an inbuilt function that allows me to do this?

Comment: Have a look at this [Calculate Google Maps distance between addresses](http://www.analystcave.com/excel-calculate-distances-between-addresses/).

Comment: Google Maps will do this, with or without using the api. To do this using the api you would need to have relatively good programming skills.